# MS Graph api: access other users data

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am building a native application that uses Microsoft Graph.

I am using the OAuth2 authorization workflow to get the authorization code:
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize?resource=https://graph.microsoft.com&prompt=admin_consent

I would like my application to be able to read all messages in any user's mailbox (when an admin is logged in). I can read the mail of the signed-in user (the admin in this case) but not the other users (I get a 403 error). I have checked every single permission (delegated) in my app's Azure admin. When I grant access to the app in the browser, I get a huge list of permissions, including "Read and write user mail".

I have the same problem with mailboxSettings, even if the login page asks me to grant "Read and write user mailbox settings" permission (among many others). I'm using the following query value: prompt=admin_consent when requesting an authorization code.

Is there a way an admin can access all other users info?

Thanks

Comment: I am facing similar issue. Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 1):

With Mail.Read permission, even if you are logged in as admin, you cannot read mail from another user's mailbox.  With Mail.Read.Shared permission, if you have access to another user's mailbox, you will be able to sign in as you and read their mail.

Comment: So I have Mail.Read.Shared permission,and I have access to another user's mailbox, How do i tell graph to read the other mailbox? what  does the graph url look like?